# Bluetooth share option disapper for sharing option

Tags: android, bluetooth

While trying to share multiple audio files, Bluetooth option is not coming in sharing list

[image]

I am using below code

```
                ArrayList<Uri> pathuri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                    pathuri.add(i, Uri.fromFile(new File(path[i])));
                }
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pathuri);
                sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                        getString(R.string.send_via)));
```

Above code working fine in Android 4.4 and below.But not working in Android 5.0.

And while trying below code, Bluetooth option is coming. But it is giving below error

```
                ArrayList<Uri> pathuri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                    pathuri.add(i, Uri.fromFile(new File(path[i])));
                }
                Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pathuri);
```

OR

```
                sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                        pathuri);
                sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                        getString(R.string.send_via)));
```

Error:

```
Key android.intent.extra.STREAM expected Parcelable but value was a java.util.ArrayList.  The default value <null> was returned.
Attempt to cast generated internal exception:
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to android.os.Parcelable
```

Can anyone help me on this issue, Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found solution of above problem:

```
                    ArrayList<Uri> pathuri = new ArrayList<Uri>();
                    for (int i = 0; i < path.length; i++) {
                        pathuri.add(i, Uri.fromFile(new File(path[i])));
                    }
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
                    sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                            pathuri);
                    sendIntent.setType("*/*"); // previously i am using sendIntent.setType("audio/*");
                    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent,
                            getString(R.string.send_via)));
```